# TFS change SharePoint links

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

Our company has a SharePoint server where we have to store all of our documents, our TFS 2013 has links to this SharePoint server.  We have been told that the company is getting a new SharePoint server which will have a different url

This means that all links within our TFS need to be repointed to the new SharePoint site

Does anyone know of a way to change the links without someone having to go in to each PBI; see if it has any links; if it does then remove the old link and add a new one?

We have 100's of documents and would rather not have to do this manually so any help will be much appreciated

This is all beyond my control, all I've been told is they are migrating our SharePoint site to another server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to work out how to do this using the PowerShell Cmdlets but I have been able to write a program to do this using [Team Foundation Work Item Tracking Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.aspx)

I have looped through each of the work items and their external links, if the link is to our old SharePoint site then:

- I remove the old link
- Add a new link with location of the same document on the new SharePoint

Answer (score 1):

You can write a PowerShell script that will open all PBIs and change the links to the new SharePoint. In order to get access to TFS from PowerShell scripts you have to install Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools and check the PowerShell Cmdlets option during installation.

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like I need to do some more reading on how to do it but it does look like it might be possible